# How to add parameter in between static URL in angular router?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'd like to configure a path like "name1/:id/name2" and navigate to it. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use router configuration

```
routes = [
 {path: 'name1/:id/name2', component: SomeComponent}
]
```

and navigate to it by `this.router.navigate(['name1', id, 'name2'])` or using element
`<a [routerLink]="['name1', id, 'name2']">link</a>`